# Can someone explain to me the apache log "[info] server seems busy"?

Tags: apache-2.2

This is the log:

> [info] server seems busy, (you may need to
> increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers), spawning 8 children,
> there are 17 idle, and 37 total children
>
> [info] server seems busy, (you may need to increase StartServers, or
> Min/MaxSpareServers), spawning 8 children, there are 18 idle, and 37
> total children
>
> [info] server seems busy,
> (you may need to increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers),
> spawning 8 children, there are 18 idle, and 37 total children
>
> [info] server seems busy, (you may need to increase
> StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers), spawning 8 children, there are
> 19 idle, and 37 total children
>
> [info]
> server seems busy, (you may need to increase StartServers, or
> Min/MaxSpareServers), spawning 8 children, there are 18 idle, and 38
> total children
>
> [info] server seems busy,
> (you may need to increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers),
> spawning 8 children, there are 15 idle, and 39 total children

The message isn't very clear to me and apache2 documentation doesn't help either.

What are those children, why is it spawning 8, what are idle children and what are total children? What is it trying to tell me?

Answer (score 2):

The children are threads or more abstractly 'workers' that are used to accept() and process connections.

It is spawning 8 because Apache HTTPd has detected an average load that would be better served by more workers. It is 'faster' to 'pre-spawn' these workers. IE: If there are 8 requests being handled and a 9th comes in, Apache must spawn a 9th worker to accept and process the connection. This is a relatively expensive process (the spawning). Apache is just dynamically adjusting its worker pool to the load.

Idle children are children that are waiting to begin working on a connection. total children reflects the size of the entire pool. Here you have approximately 20 'working' workers (non-idle).

Comment: Good answer. IIRC "accept()" is called in a central process/thread. Upon a connection, the resulting socket is then handed to a worker thread/process. (Linux kernel 3.11 has changed that though, multiple accepts will be possible.)

Comment: admittedly I am not intimately familiar with the inner code / process. Good call though.

Comment: So how come there are 18 idle when he spawned only 8?

Comment: Also, how StartServers and/or Min/MaxSpareServers reflect these values? Are servers = workers?

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200507.mbox/%3C8C29B2F93BAE9047A906EF6D6F9C5D43469B2B@exchange2k301.gaia.fr%3E `When load increases and IdleServers falls below MinSpareServers, new processes will be forked.
When load falls, eventually the processes in excess of MaxSpareServers will be terminated.`